Closing a custom pop-up menu In Justpy
I'm using Justpy v0.14 and I'm trying to implement a very simple pop-up menu. There is a button, when clicked a pop-up shows up. The pop-up should be closed when a user clicks somewhere outside the pop-up area.
Any idea how to do it?
I tried this:
import justpy as jp

def home_page(request):
    wp = jp.WebPage()

    userButton = jp.Button(type='button', aria_expanded='false', aria_haspopup='true', text="user", a=wp)
    userMenu = jp.Div(classes='absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none invisible', role='menu', aria_orientation='vertical', aria_labelledby='user-menu-button', tabindex='-1', a=wp)
    p1 = jp.Div(a=userMenu, text="Option 1")
    userMenu.isVisible = False
    
    userButton.userMenu = userMenu

    def userMenuClick_out(self, msg):
        if userMenu.isVisible:
            userMenu.set_class('invisible')
            userMenu.isVisible = False

    def toggleUserMenu(self, msg):
        if self.userMenu.isVisible:
            self.userMenu.set_class('invisible')
            self.userMenu.isVisible = False
        else:
            self.userMenu.set_class('visible')
            self.userMenu.isVisible = True

    userMenu.on('click__out', userMenuClick_out)
    userButton.on('click', toggleUserMenu)
    
    return wp

jp.justpy(home_page)

However the click__out event is triggered also when the user clicks the button (because the button is outside the menu), so the result is that the pop-up is closed immediately after being opened.
I tried to move assigning the event handler for click__out to the event handler of the button click, hoping it will be assigned dynamically. But this doesn't seem to work.

Yes, the example from http://justpy.io/tutorial/handling_events/#the-click__out-event works fine however this is another case. In that example there is one element and we are handling clicks in- and out- of it. In my case I have two elements. One (the button) handles 'click' to open another element. The the other element handles 'click__out' to close it. In my case, when I click the button it also triggers the 'click__out' event which effectively closes the pop-up.

It seems I found a solution which is physically adding and removing the pop-up component. This is less efficient then hiding but at least works as expected.
Here comes the code which works for me:
import justpy as jp

def home_page(request):
    wp = jp.WebPage()

    userButton = jp.Button(type='button', aria_expanded='false', aria_haspopup='true', text="user", a=wp)
    userMenu = jp.Div(a=wp, classes='absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none', role='menu', aria_orientation='vertical', aria_labelledby='user-menu-button', tabindex='-1')
    userMenu.show = False
    p1 = jp.Div(a=userMenu, text="Option 1")
    userMenu.isVisible = False
    
    userButton.userMenu = userMenu

    def userMenuClick_out(self, msg):
        if userMenu.isVisible:
            userMenu.show = False
            userMenu.isVisible = False

    async def toggleUserMenu(self, msg):
        if not self.userMenu.isVisible:
            self.userMenu.show = True
            self.userMenu.isVisible = True

    userMenu.on('click__out', userMenuClick_out)
    userButton.on('click', toggleUserMenu)
    
    return wp

jp.justpy(home_page)

